# How to write full message while commiting with git?

Tags: git, git-commit

This is how I commit with git :

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'added theme color and image error handling'
```

But it throws an error for the commit message :

```
error: pathspec 'theme' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'color' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'and' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'image' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'error' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'handling'' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

How can I write full commit message with git ?

Comment: Are you using any git hooks invoked by `git commit`?

Comment: use git commit without `-m` to open editor ; if commit fails again, if can be due to hooks

Comment: Try with double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just USE **double quotes instead of single if you are window user**:

git commit -m "initial commit" instead of git commit -m 'initial commit'